# How to develop a custom keyboard with toolbar / Keyboard menu?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-keyboard

I see this github projects:-

https://github.com/rkkr/simple-keyboard

And

https://github.com/NlptechProduct/Android-Keyboard

but i don't understand code.

Please give me any suggestion or demo And which not use KeyboardView because this is deprecated.

> This class was deprecated in API level 29. This class is deprecated
>   because this is just a convenient UI widget class that application.
>   Developers can re-implement on top of existing public APIs. If you
>   have already depended on this class, consider copying the
>   implementation from AOSP into your project or re-implementing a
>   similar widget by yourself.

or explain me about android keyboard how can i develop.

or suggest me how can i develop my custom keyboard app.

Comment: This is what Google suggests and how I made it work

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63689954/3101777