# KeyboardView is deprecated in android

Tags: android

`KeyboardView` has been deprecated official by android team in API level 29 and i didn't able to find the alternative way for this. Please let me know if there any alternative?

Comment: Any update? This seems to be the only question addressing this...

Comment: https://github.com/hijamoya/KeyboardView, you can try my library, I just do the copy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only solution Google suggests is copying [KeyboardView.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/b798689749c64baba81f02e10cf2157c747d6b46/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java) and [Keyboard.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java) files to your local project from Android AOSP. With some customization I managed to make it work as old **deprecated** `KeyboardView` and `Keyboard` Android's classes.

You will also have your local copy of **com.android.internal.R** attributes (stylable) from  [from here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#7740)

You can notice, it is annotated as

```
<!-- {@deprecated Copy this definition into your own application project.} -->
```

Google:

> This class was deprecated in **API level 29**. This class is deprecated
> because this is just a convenient UI widget class that application
> developers can re-implement on top of existing public APIs. If you
> have already depended on this class, consider copying the
> implementation from AOSP into your project or re-implementing a
> similar widget by yourselves

Comment: Keyboard.java has **deprecated** annotation -.-
this is the correct [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/b798689749c64baba81f02e10cf2157c747d6b46/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java)

Comment: @isthemartin  Yes, and as I stated in my answer, you should copy the deprecated class and make minor changes. One of such change is remove the deprecated annotation. The class itself works well. It is what Google suggests

Comment: is right, so I have one more question: what happen with **com.android.internal.R** ? it seems that cannot be found on my project

Comment: @isthemartin  You also need to copy it from Android Open Source. See my updated answer

Comment: By following your answer, I'm facing an error as "Error inflating class com.android.urdu.KeyboardView". Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/66239268/12050970. I'm facing this issue.

Comment: @NabeelAhmed Did you resolve the issue??

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell where to find com.android.internal.R.id.keyboardView and com.android.internal.R.id.button_close?

Comment: How can we keep recyclerview as the keyboard view instead of the keypad, do anyone aware of that ?