# How to create a custom Keyboard?

Tags: android

Android had deprecated the `Keyboard` and `Keyboard view` classes in API 29.

How can I make a custom keyboard without these classes?

All the tutorials and examples I found online use them.

thanks!

Comment: Here, what google suggests and how I made it work   https://stackoverflow.com/a/63689954/3101777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Keyboard`, according to the deprecation message, is just a UI widget class.

> **This class was deprecated in API level 29**.
>   This class is deprecated because this is just a convenient UI widget class that application developers can re-implement on top of existing public APIs. If you have already depended on this class, consider copying the implementation from AOSP into your project or re-implementing a similar widget by yourselves

If you want to follow the tutorials that use it, just copy the class [from the google source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java) into your project and use it locally. Otherwise, you can customise it by creating it from scratch and giving the widget the look and feel that you want.